# How to save a matlab figure on a GUI disabled machine

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am working on a machine wherein the graphics option has been  disabled in the matlab . I am trying to save a matlab figure which has been rendered using imshow command , and oven that some lines has been plotted on it . I tried to  switch off the figure handle , but everytime it return the following error :

```
IMSHOW unable to display image.
```

Is there any way of saving the figure ?

PS: I know I can work on the image matrix and then imwrite it but I want to directly save the figure handle .

Answer (score 0):

Look at [imsave.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsave.html)

It allows you to save the content of a figure using its handles: `imsave(Figure_handles)`

Comment: before even saving it , I should at least be able to "imshow" the image , but it is returning error as mentioned above.

Comment: did you try the code? I'm not sure to understand then I thought you only wanted to save the content of the figure